# Suggestion: it should use CSS3 var() to replace $variable

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I have read bootstrap source codes and found that

SCSS:

```
    body {
      margin: 0; // 1
      font-family: $font-family-base;
      @include font-size($font-size-base);
      font-weight: $font-weight-base;
      line-height: $line-height-base;
      color: $body-color;
      text-align: $body-text-align;
      background-color: $body-bg; // 2
      -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; // 3
      -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba($black, 0); // 4
    }
```

CSS:

```
body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: var(--bs-font-sans-serif);
  font-size: 1rem;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 1.5;
  color: #212529;
  background-color: #fff;
  -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}
```

It is good to use "font-family: var(--bs-font-sans-serif)", I think.

But "color: $body-color;" is not good. It is not good for creating themes.

You should use "color: var(--bs-dark);" to replace the attribute setting.

Thanks.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this doesn't appear to be a programming problem and instead feedback for Bootstrap

Comment: Yes. it is not a programming problem. but I can not find a channel to express the suggestion. I can close it

Comment: You can file a new issue at https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues instead